# PHP Return text field data only if box is checked

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a simple email order form, but my PHP skills are lacking. I have 4 text fields, and I only want them returned if a checkbox is selected

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks" name="cards" id="cards" value="YES" /> Business Cards
<label for="cardname1">Name (exactly as it should appear on card): </label><input type="text" name="CardName1" id="CardName1">
<label for="title1">Title: </label><input type="text" name="title1" id="title1">
<label for="Phone1">Phone: </label><input type="text" name="Phone1" id="Phone1">
<label for="Fax1">Fax: </label><input type="text" name="Fax1" id="Fax1">
```

I'm currently returning

```
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone:\n $phone";
```

from another part of the form. What is the simplest way to include the additional data if the box is checked? Ideally, I'd like to combine the data into one variable

```
$carddata = $Cardname1, $title1, $Phone1, $Fax1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the checkbox is checked. If so, append the values to `$body`. I used a little "trick" with `implode()` that simplifies this a bit:

```
if ($Cards === 'Yes') { // make sure your checkbox ichecked. You need to put the real value here.
    $body .= "\n " . implode("\n ", array($Cardname1, $title1, $Phone1, $Fax1));
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much. Using this format, however, leads me to another question I've been banging away at since you posted. I have 4 sets of card data ($Cardname1, $Cardname2, etc.) I was going to use $carddata# (see original post) to simplify. Doing it the way you suggested, should i create separate $body inputs for each set, or can I combine multiple implode arrays in that function and how?